# When using list for gridview's datasource, how do I set the column name on the list?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Basically I have a gridview that is using a list as it's datasource.  How do I tell the gridview which column in the list is which?

```
        // Regions
        Dictionary<int, string> regions = (Master as SiteMaster).getCustomerRegions((Master as SiteMaster).userBasic_XsiteCustomerID);
        List<List<string>> regionsList = new List<List<string>>();
        foreach (int curRegionID in regions.Keys)
        {
            List<string> curRegion = new List<string>();
            Dictionary<string, string> curRegionDetail = (Master as SiteMaster).getRegionDetail(curRegionID);
            curRegion.Add(curRegionID.ToString());
            curRegion.Add(curRegionDetail["regionName"]);
            regionsList.Add(curRegion);
        }
        grv_regionManagement.DataSource = regionsList;
        grv_regionManagement.DataBind();
```

So it's throwing me an error that say regionID is not define, which make sense since there is no where that tell the gridview that the first column is actually the regionID.

Here is the code in ASP.NET for defining the regionID field:

```
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="regionID" InsertVisible="False" 
                SortExpression="regionID" Visible="False">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("regionID") %>'></asp:Label>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("regionID") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: you can easily define your column in `gridview`. What's the problem actually?

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't know what the corresponding column is in the list.

Comment: If you're only using the strings from the Dictionary object, why don't you assign that as the data source and then your region id will be in the Key field and the region name will be in the Value field?  It looks like you're trying to define a separate list for each column, which won't work.

Comment: I have other table with more than 2 fields, so a 2D list is neccesary.

Comment: so what does your gridview look like if you have variable columns?

Comment: It's not variable, I setup my list to be exactly the same size as the gridview.  It look like a normal gridview table... if I can get it to work.

Comment: You'll need to create an object that contains references to the objects containing the fields you use in a single row. Then use the collection of those objects as your data source.  Then you can reference the fields in the markup using Bind("[object1 reference name].[object1 fieldname]").  At any rate, a list of lists is not the same as a 2D list!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than a list of lists of strings, have a list of objects that have your columns as properties. You can use these properties as the datasource for each column.

Comment: you can use linq projection to get a subset of the data.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to let go of the list, then form a DataTable from your list and then assign the DataTable as the DataSource. Refer [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588329/how-to-set-a-gridview-columns-text-depending-on-other-columns-which-are-binded/10588405#10588405) and modify it to populate the DataTable from your list.

This way, you won't have to worry about telling your gridview anything.